# SharePoint incremental backup

Tags: backup

We already have full and differential backup jobs on our farm and I also want to take incremental backup from our SharePoint farm, is that possible? what is the power-shell script for incremental backup?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Backup-SPFarm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607881.aspx), you can pass the Differential parameter on the -BackupMethod switch which will be the changes between the last backup (diff or full) and 'now'.

Comment: Thanks, but I need incremental backup and not Differential.

Comment: Ah, yeah your only option is using T-SQL backups, then.